# Кто-либо или кто-либо другой?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно сказать "кто-либо" или "кто-либо другой"? В чем разница?

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что разница есть, и она во вторичности второго (простите за тавтологию) сочетания слов. "Кто-либо другой" - это не просто кто-либо, а "кто-либо на новом этапе действия".Согласен с Валентином, что лучше звучит "кто-нибудь"или "кто-то". Например, кто-нибудь ответил на вопрос нашего форума, а кто-нибудь другой не согласился с данным ответом и внес свое предложение, отличное от предшествующего."Кто-то дал ответ, а кто-либо другой пусть дополняет этот ответ"

Comment: Да, вы правы. Значение немного различаются, например: "Подойдите сюда кто-либо (=кто-нибудь" и "Подойдите сюда кто-либо другой (не тот, кто подошел первым)".    
Но, как я и говорил, всё зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сказать и так, и так. Смысл у них одинаковый. Всё зависит от контекста. Где-то красивее употребить первый вариант, а где-то второй.    
Я бы посоветовал вместо "кто-либо" употреблять "кто-нибудь". Так, по-моему лучше.